# How to use pandas transform function to divide each row with max value grouped by another column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
      country_code  confirmed_cases  count_date
0              AFG          38113.0  2020-08-27
1              ALB           8927.0  2020-08-27
2              DZA          42619.0  2020-08-27
3              AND           1098.0  2020-08-27
4              AGO           2332.0  2020-08-27
...            ...              ...         ...
18963          PSE          27919.0  2020-09-10
18964          ESH             10.0  2020-09-10
18965          YEM           1999.0  2020-09-10
18966          ZMB          13112.0  2020-09-10
18967          ZWE           7429.0  2020-09-10
```

I need to calculate maximum 'confirmed_cases' for each date (across all country codes) and then divide each country's confirmed_cases of that date by the max value.

I can get max values with:

```
df.groupby('count_date')['confirmed_cases'].max()
```

and then merge this with original dataframe etc. but I think this can be done easily using transform function. Please guide.

Comment: Try: `df['confirmed_cases'] / df.groupby('count_date')['confirmed_cases'].transform('max')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this can be done in two ways.

1. Divide by [groupby transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) max:

```
df['confirmed_cases'] / df.groupby('count_date')['confirmed_cases'].transform('max') #as pointed out by Chris A
```

2. [groupby transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) and a lambda:

```
df.groupby('count_date').confirmed_cases.transform(lambda x: x/x.max())
```